# Simulator not reflecting my changes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, simulator

My simulator is not reflecting changes I make in the storyboard. The simulator lunches as blank. The app is on the simulator, and I see it. But I cannot see the changes. I have a simple view controller, I have table view controller, single page view controller and tab bar controller. I change the name of the controllers to reflect on the tab bar controller but that does not show up in the simulator.

here is what i see:

2014-10-07 23:33:39.470 sim[1218:303] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin/sim: Did not find an executable file at the path: '/Users/dmitriysinayskiy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fotilo-erasfnjopnjainelkdsyjarnwzze/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Fotilo.app'

what do i do now?

Comment: It can't find your app at that path, where/how are you building it.

Comment: quit the Xcode and simulator once. And delete your derived data also

Comment: How do I delete derived data?      I also noticed that there is no "developer" folder in my library

Comment: Xcode > preference > Location(last) > Derived data (1st). you can see little arrow. tap on it. it will open finder with "Derived Data" folder name. delete all that data (from trash also). that folder contains all your project name which you open once.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. I'll do that then clean the project and run it again. I hope that helps. Will post update when done

Comment: this didn't work. i deleted all content in derived data. from bin too. relaunched Xcode. ran the project. same thing. blank screen

Comment: @DimaSin try to reset your simulator and run again. "reset contents and settings"

Comment: @roxen I did that. I did everything short of reinstalling Mavericks as new and downloading Xcode again.